# Un-check using jQuery, but the checkbox is still deemed 'successful control' and is submitted

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I found out (accompanied with copious amount of pain) if we start with:

```
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" id="cb1" name="some-name" value="some-value"/>
```

and later use jQuery under some event:

```
$('#cb1').prop('checked', false);
```

the checkbox does lose it's check mark, however, when the corresponding form is submitted, the checkbox is still part of form-data, it being a 'successful control'.

The only way to make the checkbox 'not successful' (and preclude it from being submitted to the server) is to:

```
$('#cb1').removeAttr('checked');
```

Is there a way to make the check box not 'successful' using jQuery (or javascript)? So that it's not submitted to the server.

Thanks.

Comment: Where's your code that deems it a 'successful control'?

Comment: There's probably something on the server side like `if (some-name.checked) { ...` instead of `if (some-name.checked == "checked") { ...`

Comment: The control will be submitted, but not with the value (as if it was set to true).

Comment: @j08691 it is part of a large (and very old) enterprise java application. But essentially a form with a lot of form-controls.

Answer (score -1):

The request will send all data, including the checkbox, so you will receive the value if checked and null or empty if not checked. You need to handle it in server-side.

```
   <input type="checkbox" name="cb" value="yeah">

   // server if checked
   $_POST['cb'] === yeah

   // server if not checked
   $_POST['cb'] === empty
```

So you don't need control like this

```
   isset($_POST['cb'])
```

And you need this

```
   !empty($_POST['cb'])
```

I assume that's PHP but is the same in all languages.

Good luck

Answer (score -1):

You shouldnt use `checkbox="false"`, because for the browser it still counts as checked. If you want to prevent it from being sent use the `disabled` attribute or `.removeAttr('checked')` method.